# Sum the total Value Of Report Item Text Box Value In SSRS REPORTS

Tags: reporting-services

[Original Picture Of My Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsVSC.png)

[Need Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJp0K.png)

I Have tried like this ----

```
Public Shared Dim TotalSum As Decimal = 0

Public Function AddToTotal(ByVal value As Decimal) As Decimal
    TotalSum += value
    Return value
End Function

Public Function GetSum() As Decimal
    Return TotalSum
End Function
```

.

```
=Code.AddToTotal(ReportItems!Textbox1.Value)

=Code.GetTotalSum()
```

but like this was not working

[I have tried using code this answer showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8pEi.png)

Comment: Why do you need to use custom code? Why can't you just group by customer and then add a subtotal row, then a simple SUM will work.

Comment: the data is coming from a mainframe so i'm getting repeating values in fields which turns into causes & SUM to be way over expected result. That's why i have used this method .

Comment: You'll probably need to pass in the group fields to the function too (Customer etc), store it in a variable and reset the TotalSum value to zero when the group field(s) change. If you can show a sample of data as it comes out of you dataset query and the expected results based on that sample data, then that would be helpful as there may be other ways to do this.